# Java ImageIO.write sends more data than ImageIO.read receives?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, javax.imageio

I'm trying to send an image over a socket, and I've come across a strange issue.. ImageIO.write is sending MORE data than ImageIO.read receives. For example if I have the code below in a loop:

(Client side)

```
out.writeByte(222);//magic num for testing
out.writeByte(blockSize);
out.writeByte(x / blockSize);
out.writeByte(y / blockSize);
ImageIO.write(part, "PNG", out);
```

(Server sided)

```
if (din.readUnsignedByte() != 222) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
int partSize = din.readUnsignedByte();
int partX = partSize * din.readUnsignedByte();
int partY = partSize * din.readUnsignedByte();
BufferedImage part = ImageIO.read(din);
```

On the second iteration, the magic number will fail because ImageIO.read has not read all of the data sent from the other end. Why is this? It seems like a major issue. Or am I missing something?

EDIT: This seems to be a confirmed bug as of 2008-04-14. Bug ID [6687964](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6687964). Why hasn't this been fixed?.. agh.

Comment: Looks like you will have to read the unread part of the image trailer until you get the 222 again.

Comment: In theory that works, however every 256 bytes or so a 222 is actually in the image data, meaning I get a corrupt image.. This is a MAJOR issue, I don't see why it's not fixed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I came up with as a workaround:

(bout being a ByteArrayOutputStream, and out being the socket stream)

```
                        ImageIO.write(part, "jpg", bout);
                        out.writeShort(bout.size());
                        bout.writeTo(out);
                        bout.reset();
```

This code will send the size of the image as a short before writing the image, thus preventing the bug.

Comment: It will prevent the bug if you write compensating code at the receiver to ensure you've read that many bytes, which you haven't shown here, and which is non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue. After the program has received the file, send a confirmation back to the sender. If the sender writes an escape character `new String("\n").getBytes()` then flushes the OutputStream it should end the buffered stream and allow you to `InputStream.ReadLine()` on the other end. This should get the excess data and the next repetition of the loop will get the new image data. Annoying I know, but it works

Comment: This works however as I noted above, occasionally you will get an \n in the actual image data..